# How do I filter or search email messages in Mutt by a flag?

Tags: linux, mutt

For example , if I want to list only unseen/unread emails?  I know you can use some sort of expressions when doing a search with / but not sure what is supported.  Am I able to specify a flag based search for example?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the "limit" command.  E.g. type "`l~U`" (that starts with an ell for "limit", not a 1 or an I....) to get all unread <s>("new")</s> messages.

The [Mutt Manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/) is very good.  See [section 3.1](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns) for details on search expressions like "~U" for "Unread".

**Update**: I've fixed this to use "U" for Unread, rather than "N" for New.

Comment: New is not the same as "unread". What you *really* want is ~U, if you want unread messages.

Comment: I used to classify mail into folders by procmail, but since one e-mail might fall into several classes, I was running into issues with redundancy. Mutt's filtering postpones the classification until I need it and solves my issues.